# How to get the value label of store config fields with source models

Tags: magento

I'm trying to iterate over each config field to get the value of every field for each scope level. Here's the code so far:

$path will be an array of config paths like 'general/country/default', 'general/country/allow', 'general/region/display_all', etc. The function below will iterate over each $path element.

```
$value = Mage::getConfig()->getNode($path, 'default');

// ...

foreach (Mage::app()->getWebsites() as $website) {
    $value = Mage::getConfig()->getNode($path, 'website', $website->getCode());

    // ...

    foreach ($website->getGroups() as $group) {                
        foreach ($group->getStores() as $store) {
            $value = Mage::getConfig()->getNode($path, 'store', $store->getCode());

            // ...

        }
    }
}
```

This works fine except on dropdowns and other fields. On a Yes/No dropdown it will return 1/0 instead of Yes/No. On a country dropdown it will return US instead of United States, etc.

I'm pretty sure I need to run the returned values through the source model but I don't know how to get the source model for each $path programmatically?

Or maybe there's another way...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you can get the source model of a config setting.
You can integrate this in your script.

**Step 1**
You need a method to get the contents of the `system.xml` files.

```
$config = Mage::getConfig()->loadModulesConfiguration('system.xml')->applyExtends();
```

**Step 2**
You need a way to 'translate' the config node name (`general/country/allow`) to the path from the `system.xml` (`sections/general/groups/country/fields/allow`).
The mechanism is this

```
general/country/allow -------------------|
   |       |                             |
   |       |--------------|              |
   |                      |              |
   |-------|              |              |
           |              |              |
sections/general/groups/country/fields/allow
   |               |               |
   |               |               |
   |-------always the same---------|
```

Here is a simple function.

```
function getSystemPath($path) {
    $newPath = '';
    $parts = explode('/', $path);
    if (count($parts) != 3) { //you must have at least 3 parts in the node name
        return '';
    }
    return 'sections/'.$parts[0].'/groups/'.$parts[1].'/fields/'.$parts[2];

}
```

**Step 3.**
Now get the `source_model` node

```
$path = 'general/country/allow'
$node = $config->getNode(getSystemPath($path)); //get the corresponding system.xml path from the config loaded at step 1.
if ($node && $node->source_model){  //if there is a source model
    //instantiate the model - use getSingleton in case there are more fields that use the same source model
    $model = Mage::getSingleton((string)$node->source_model);
    //get options
    $options = $model->toOptionArray();
    //do something with $options.
}
```

**[Edit]**

If you want to load the `system.xml` file for a single module you can do this:

```
$configFile = Mage::getConfig()->getModuleDir('etc', 'Mage_Catalog').DS.'system.xml';
$string = file_get_contents($configFile);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string, 'Varien_Simplexml_Element');
```

But keep this in mind. A module can override or add elements in the configuration area for an other module.

Comment: it is possible to load system.xml file for specific module ? @Marius

Comment: @KeyurShah. I've added a way to do that to the answer. It looks nicer in the answer than in a comment.

Comment: Thanks @Marius it works great. Is there any way to cache the $config object to prevent loading it on each page load? I tried using Magento cache but it said that that object can't be serialized.

Comment: If it doesn't work with `Mage::app()->saveCache($config, 'some_cache_id_here', array('some_tags'), 36000)` I don't know how you could do it.